# Can you use a regular expression in a Django template conditional?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to determine if a template variable in a Django template satisfies a regular expression?  In the following template, I want to set the CSS class for the paragraph tag that contains the help text based on whether or not the help text for that field satisfies a regular expression.  Here is the template with some pseudocode thrown in:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% if field.help_text %}
      {% if field.help_text|lower (BEGINS WITH SOME STRING) %}         # Pseudocode
        <p class="select-help-text">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
      {% else %}
        <p class="help-text">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For example, if the help_text as defined in the associated form starts with the text string "Hold down Ctrl", then the CSS class should be set to `select-help-text`, otherwise it should just be set to `help-text`.

I understand that Django regular expressions are based on Python regexes, but Python regex evaluations always seems to be done using the `re` module which isn't accessible in a Django template.  I also looked through the Django documentation but couldn't find a way to do this.

**UPDATE**

I still can't get this code to work.

Melvyn, who answered below, is technically correct.  You should avoid putting conditional logic in Django templates.  To that end, I changed my template per the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields):

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% if field.help_text %}
      <p class="help-text">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I then added an `__init__` method to my forms ModelForm class that looks at the label for the form fields that shouldn't have their help text displayed and sets `help_text` to a "falsey" value so the condition in the template will fail:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for visible in self.visible_fields():
        if visible.field.label == 'foo' or visible.field.label == 'bar' or visible.field.label == 'baz':
            visible.field.help_text = False
```

However, I'm still seeing the help text whether I set `help_text` to False or `None` or an empty string.  Is this some type of timing issue or have I made a mistake that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Comment: This is caused by how ModelForm overrides things. basically, you should override Meta.help_texts instead. I haven't found where model form does it, but with a normal form your code works as expected. Overriding help_texts is however quite unpractical for your case.

Comment: Ok, you may be having the same problem as me: model forms `title()` their labels, so your matching may not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTL (Django Template Language) is not meant to program. In fact, I wouldn't even write a template tag for this. In your view (or form, or field or widget), you have all the power to change the help text to a 2-tuple or dict with a label, so why don't ya ;)

Perhaps the best approach is in the field or widget and just add the desired class to the widget based on the help text.

### Overriding model form fields

So, to provide the answer for the update, this is the trimmed down example I used:

`models.py`

```py
from django.db import models


class Sensor(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, verbose_name="visible", help_text="Colors are visible"
    )
    sound = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, verbose_name="audible", help_text="Sounds are audible"
    )
```

`forms.py`

```py
class BasicModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            normalized = visible.label.lower()
            if "audible" == normalized:
                visible.help_text = ""

    class Meta:
        model = Sensor
        fields = "__all__"
```

`tests.py`

```py
from django.template import Template, Context

class FormTest(TestCase):
    def test_modelform(self):
        form = BasicModelForm()
        self.assertEqual(form["sound"].help_text, "")

    def test_template(self):
        form = BasicModelForm()
        context = Context({"form": form})
        template = Template("{{ form.sound.help_text }} | {{form.color.help_text}}")
        actual = template.render(context)
        self.assertEqual(""" | Colors are visible""", actual)
```

It failed before normalizing the label value. I used the test to have PyCharm break at the assignment, but it never got to the assignment, so then I braked at the if statement to see "Audible" instead of "audible".

Comment: I agree, but this looks more like comment than answer

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll take it under advisement.

Comment: Ok, thought about it. No, it's an answer, because I'm addressing the X problem in an XY problem. Hopefully this prevents someone from writing a template tag that does regexes, cause we have enough of that poor design laying around the floor here.

Comment: I am not against essence you are trying to project with what you written.
I don't personally find template tags appealing nor DTL itself in modern age of SPA and also pointing that logic should be kept in view ( at least that is my opinion ), but this generally looks like one sentence comment material for me, maybe it is just my conflated opinion of what answer is and how concise it should be.  I have got bit off topic here so sorry on that, just tried to clarify what I meant.

Comment: @Melvyn If no one can spot my issue in the next day, I will give you credit.  My code and yours are doing essentially the same thing.  I understand your code and see why it should work. I did change my 'super' statement to 'super()' as you have. I even set a breakpoint before the 'if' to verify that I'm setting help_text to a blank string on the correct fields. But when I print 'field.help_text' in the template, it's not blank. So something is happening between when __init__ runs and the final template is rendered. I don't know what it is. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Can you create a testcase similar to mine above that works for your setup and see if the template test fails? I'm starting to wonder if you're importing the wrong form or looking at a cache. There's zero reason for Django forms library to restore help texts if they're empty, nor do I see any other calls to `fields_for_model` that could explain this.

Comment: @Melvyn I would but I can't afford to spend more time on this issue at present, especially since I have a work-around.  I did give you credit and really appreciate your answer and your persistence in trying to help me track down the source of the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I understand. I hope it's isolated and not an issue that pops up in other views. I have tried a few more things to reproduce it but just can't.